# PHP: Function no query & return

Tags: php, mysql

I hope that someone sharp on PHP can help me with problem, that i really don't understand.

I have 2 scripts. 1: test.php 2:functions.php.

I created a little test where i called a functions in functions.php frim test.php and it work fine. I got a return and it was as expected. I also have a third script register.php where i have a query to a database and that work fine.

So I wanted the query to work as a function written in functions.php

Problem: It seems that it won't make the database query! But there is createt a connection

If I move the exactly same query to test.php, it works! Is there some kind of speciel reason for this? I quit new to php, but knows a little about Java, C, JavaScript, Python.

I have checked that my include / require is all in order.

1: test.php:

```
 <?php
 require 'includes/functions.php';
 $name = 'testuser';
 $_ok = 0;
 $_ok = check_username ($name);
 printf ( 'Navn i database?: ' . $_ok . '<br>' );
 ?>
```

2: functions.php:

```
<?php
require 'includes/db_connect.php';
// Check connection
if (! $mysqli) {
die ( 'mysqli_init_failed' );
}
if (mysqli_connect_errno ()) {
die ( 'Failed to connect to the Database, Sorry..! errorcode: ' .
mysqli_connect_errno() . ' <br>' . 'Error Type: ' . mysqli_connect_error ()     );
}
if ($debug_mode_c) {
print ('Connection Established: ' . mysqli_get_host_info ( $mysqli ) . '<br>') ;
print ('session_id: ' . session_id ()) . '<br>';
}
```

// Set HTML-Header to utf-8.
header ( 'Content Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );

```
 // Functions
 function check_username($_ok) {
 $name = 'testuser';
 $prep_stmt = "SELECT username FROM customs WHERE username=? LIMIT 1 ";
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $prep_stmt);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $name);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $name_db);
 mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
  if ($name == $name_db) {
  echo "hello";
  mysqli_close ($stmt);
  $_ok = 0;
  } else {
 $name = '';
  $_ok = 2;
 }
 mysqli_free_result($stmt);
 mysqli_close($stmt);
 return $_ok;
 }
```

Comment: I really hope you have some actual indentation in the original source. This is really awkward to read.

Comment: Where do you open `mysqli` connection for the database?

Comment: Thermis Beris : I'll do that in another Script 'includes/db_connect'
I know connection works and i know that the user exist in database.
All code is working, when it's in test.php. Only when moved to functions.php and call the function there is no query done. ? :-(

Comment: @RAJensen Are you sure that your connection works as expected ? Try to open the connection  on the `check_username`. If that does not work `var_dump` your statement just like this `var_dump($stmt)`. If you get `bool(false)` from the dump, then you have an error on your query!

Comment: @ Themis Beris: It did'n help to open connection on check_username.
var_dump($stmt) return NULL when using check_username(), but it works fine, when executet in test.php.
Can't figure out why query works in test.php and not in functions.php.
It's like that php-server dosen't execute lines for database query in functions.php. Wonder if the query only get executed if it's in the script, that is called by browser and for some reason, won't work if it's called when it's in "include / include_once / require" - php.script?

Comment: @RAJensen so the result of `var_dump` implies that something is wrong on your statement. I am pretty sure that something goes wrong on your connections. Try to close first connection on `check_username` and open a new one . I can't think something else !

Comment: @Themis Berit: You're right. Connection is not establish at function-call. This only happends when the code is in test.php.
Just saw that there was no read out of mysqli_get_host_info($mysqli).
Wonder why?
Could it be because when the function-call is handlet from test.php to functions.php, server only read lines from the where functions starts to it stops, and therefore it skips the top of the script, where i check for connection and the require 'includes/db_connect.php' is'n loaded???

Comment: @RAJensen This happens because every variable defined has its `variable scope` . Google it for more details!

Comment: @Thermis Beris. Thanks... It must be the problem. Found this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
As it says, it's different from C or Java. Thougt that declarations before the function, would be loaded, when calling function. Now i got a better understanding of globals in PHP. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe found the reason for no query.
Apparently the include script containing establish connection, is not loaded as the function is called in functions.php. 
When the query code is in test.php, that include functions.php, all code is read, also the connection for the database.
But even if include 'db_connect' is inside function, it won't work !?! :-(

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like noquery() function in PHP. please just check it in the include file of the database connection. you will find a user defined function in your include file of the database connection.